# OneToMany relationship using Symfony / Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony and Doctrine and I am faced with an issue :

Let's imagine we have a **User** entity and a **PhoneCall** entity with a OneToMany relationship.

If, on a page, you have to display 2 lists : **"Today"** and **"Yesterday"**, displaying each User with its related PhoneCalls **of the day** *(the PhoneCall entity has a created_at property)*, how would you get this data and pass it to the view in a clean way?

I have tried having a 'phonecalls' property on the User entity and querying the Users with their related PhoneCalls of 'today', then making another query fetching the Users with their related PhoneCalls of 'yesterday', but that does not work because when the second query fetches an object already fetched by the first query, It gives me that same object rather than another one with the PhoneCalls of the date I asked for.

**I have also thought of making a query fetching all Users, then a separate query fetching all their PhoneCalls of today, then a separate query fetching all their PhoneCalls of yesterday, but then how would I combine all of these objects together in a clean way to pass it to the view ?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can query the user's phone calls of "today" and "yesterday" in one query, and select only the phone calls with date == today in your view for the "today"s list, and the same thing for the "yesterday"s phone call list.

This method has one big advantage, it will be easier if tomorrow you want to add a list with element of "before yesterday". You simply need to update your query and your view instead of creating a new query, updating the controller and the view .

Comment: I think it is better to create a method in the model that does the query, so that query will be updated in other calls that are made in other views or controllers, making tests and updates easier.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and cleanest way is to make a method that queries the calls of a certain day in the model:

```
 phoneCallsFromDay ($ user_id, $ day) {
     return query here
 }
```

If today's call list is displayed very frequently you can create a "todayphonecalls" property in Users, which can call the above method to populate it.

```
 $ today_calls = phoneCallsFrom ($ user_id, "today date here");
```

If it is not something that is displayed continuously, it is not recommended to load User with that data permanently.

In any case, we will use the method that you create in the model to make the queries:

```
 $ today_calls = phoneCallsFrom ($ user_id, "today date here");
 $ yesterday_calls = phoneCallsFrom ($ user_id, "yesterday date here");
```

OR

```
 $ today_calls = User-> todayphonecalls;
 $ yesterday_calls = phoneCallsFrom ($ user_id, "yesterday date here");
```

if you have created that property in User.

And the variables are passed to the view. So all the business is in the controller.

In addition, this method will serve to make any call from a view for any other date you want to show.

You can even improve it by adding two dates, if the second date is not entered the query will return only the values of the first date:

```
 phoneCallsFromDay ($ user_id, $ day_from, $ date_to = null) {
     if ($ date_to === null) {
         return query $ day_from
     }
       return query from $ day_from to $ date_to
  }
```

Comment: Just for info, the Doctrine ORM is not an active record system.  Actually adding queries inside of a 'model' is not easy and typically does not work well.